# How to disable a button on page load?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

OMG sorry guys...I realized what a simple fool question I had asked....

Just using

```
btnSub.disabled = true
```

on the server side then everything is good to go....

I need to refresh my brain now....

Again, thanks for all the answers!

---

I am working on a asp.net project, on one page I have a submit button like below:

```
<input id ="btnSub" value="Submit" type="Submit" runat ="server" onclick="return isFormValid(this.form)" disabled="disabled"/>
```

What I tried to do is when the page is on load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Check some conditions, if the final result is false, then disable the submit button otherwise enable it.

I did google it but the most I have found were using jquery to disable a an asp.net button.

Any hint?

Comment: It might help to know that an input element with `runat="server"` will be an [HtmlInputControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) on the server. Of particular interest would be the `Attributes` property.

Comment: It may also be interesting to know that wiring up a submit button to inline onclick do stuff is not recommended. Instead assign a submit handler to the form instead. In there you can test if the form can be submitted or not. Like `$(function() { $("#form1").on("submit",function(e) { if (<%= nosubmit%>) e.preventDefault(); ... }); });`

Comment: Oh, there's no such thing as a "jQuery button". It's just a plain HTML button.

Comment: Thx guys, I realized this is not an issue but I need to refresh my brain...

Comment: I think you mean `btnSub.Enabled`, not `btnSub.disabled`, for server-side :)

Comment: What I could get from btnSub properties is btnSub.disabled, seems there is no btnSub.enabled on server side. I am using vs 2012 and .net 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are are after a *server-side* solution, using ASP.Net, you just need to set the `Enabled` property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx of the control in the `Page_Load.

e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (somecondition)
     {
         btnSub.Enabled = true;
     }
     else
     {
         btnSub.Enabled = false;
     }
}
```

Comment: In the old days, I used to skim through ASP.Net reference books, cover-to-cover, just to be aware of what was possible. Nowadays we try to Google everything :)

Answer (score 9):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btnSub").prop("disabled",true); 
 });
```

But if it's a form, I'd want to disable the entire form, so I'd just replace `#btnSub` with the form element instead.

Comment: Re-reading the question: Aren't they after a *server-side* solution?

Comment: $(document).ready has been deprecated since 3.0. Use `jQuery(function() { })` or `$(function () { })`